# Как получить данные из связывающей таблицы?

Tags: angular, angular10

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить данные с связующей таблицы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот данные которые приходят из сервера , и мне нужно получить authorId. Когда я делаю допустим
`console.log(this.printingEdition?.price);` то цену я получаю без проблем. А вот как получить authorId не знаю подскажите пожалуйста)

```
this.store$.pipe(select(getPrintingEdition)).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.printingEdition = data;
        console.log(this.printingEdition?.authorsId);
        
      }
)
```

printingEdition имеет тип данных модель PrintingEdition

```
export interface PrintingEdition{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    currency: CurrencyTypeEnum;
    type: PrintingTypeEnum;
    authorsId: number[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо обратиться к свойству `authorInPrintingEdition`, которое является массивом. В его первом элементе лежит объект, в котором есть информация об авторе. Вывод `authorId` в консоль: `console.log(this.printingEdition?.authorInPrintingEdition[0]?.authorId)`

Comment: так ругается потому что ```printingEdition``` это переменная тип данных которой модель ```PrintingEdition``` а эта модель не содержит authorInPrintingEdition

Comment: А так? ``console.log(this.printingEdition?.authorInPrintingEdition[0]?.authorId)``

Comment: Тоже самое, ошибка что оно не существует в ```PrintingEdition```

Comment: Моя модель выглядит вот так ```export interface PrintingEdition{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    currency: CurrencyTypeEnum;
    type: PrintingTypeEnum;
    authorsId: number[];
}```

Comment: Можно изменить модель, добавив свойство `authorInPrintingEdition`: `export interface PrintingEdition{
id: number;
title: string;
description: string;
price: number;
currency: CurrencyTypeEnum;
type: PrintingTypeEnum;
authorsId: number[]; 
authorInPrintingEdition: Array<{authorId: number}>
}`